# MBProgessHUD is immediately hidden. How to set minimum show time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show `MBProgressHUD` with customView to show user purchase something. here what i've tried

```
- (void)showInfoAlert:(int)clues {

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
    hud.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]] autorelease];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    hud.dimBackground = YES;
    NSString* msg = (clues == 1) ? @"1 Clue added to yor account." : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Clues added to yor account.", clues];
    hud.labelText = msg;
    [hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^(void){

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    }];
}
```

hud is shown for a very short time and hidden immediately. I want it to appear for atlest 3 seconds.

Comment: Why not use `[hud hide:YES afterDelay:3.0];` ?

Comment: i tried with this also but not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you're looking for is

```
/**
 * The minimum time (in seconds) that the HUD is shown. 
 * This avoids the problem of the HUD being shown and than instantly hidden.
 * Defaults to 0 (no minimum show time).
 */
@property (assign) float minShowTime;
```

In the `MBProgressHud` class.

Just add

```
hud.minShowTime = 3.f;
```

And you should be good to go.

*EDIT:* You should remove the call to `-showAnimated:whileExecutingBlock:`, because it dispatches the block in a background queue: that's why it doesn't block your HUD (which is controlled by the main thread, like every other UI component). It wouldn't have been a good idea to put the main thread to sleep anyway, since it would result in a bad user experience (and potentially have the system kill your app if that is kept blocked for too long).

You can just replace that invocation with a simple `-show:`

Comment: so no need for sleep method?

Comment: I assume it should not be needed anymore.